# How to move a variable's value into another variable in assembly

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic

I am trying to learn assembly programming with MPLAB X and a PIC18F1320 microcontroller. I have been following the MPASM User's Guide (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33014J.pdf) and have gotten an LED to blink from the RB0 pin on my microcontroller. I wrote a program to make an LED blink once every 512 ticks. I am having trouble figuring out how to change the delay from 512 to a variable quantity so I can change it somewhere else in the code. Ideally, the line

```
        movf    0xFF,count1
```

would be replaced with

```
        count1=delay1
```

where delay1 is the variable set to 0x20 earlier in the code.

Here is the code:

```
#include "p18F1320.inc"

 CONFIG  OSC = INTIO1          ; Oscillator Selection bits (Internal RC oscillator, CLKO function on RA6 and port function on RA7)

 cblock 0x20    ;start of data section
 count1         ;delay variable
 delay1         ;length of delay
 endc

        org     00          ;\
        movwf   PORTB       ; |
        movlw   0x00        ; |
        movwf   TRISB       ; |--Start program and configure I/O pins
        movlw   0x00        ; |
        movwf   ADCON1      ; |
        movlw   b'00000110' ;/

        movwf   delay1      ; Set the variable delay1=0x20
        movlw   0x20        ;/

loop    call BLINKONCE      ; Blink loop
        goto loop           ;/

BLINKONCE                   ;\
        bsf     PORTB,4     ; |
        call    DELAY       ; |--makes I/O pin RB4 turn on and off once with a delay in between
        bcf     PORTB,4     ; |
        call    DELAY       ;/
DELAY
        movf    0xFF,count1 ;I want to be able to set count1=delay1 right here

loop2   decfsz count1, 1    ; Delay loop with length=count1
        goto loop2          ;/

        return  ; end program
        end     ;/
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PIC18 device you can use the `movff` instruction to do what you are after - copy a value between two registers. The `movf` instruction only allows you to copy the value from a register into the working register.

Also the ordering of your `movlw` and `movwf` instructions at the start of the program are back to front. You call `movlw` to load a constant value out of program memory into the working register, then `movwf` to copy that value out of the working register into data memory.

This site has an online PIC simulator and tutorials that explains how this all works in more detail:

http://www.microcontrollerjs.com

Comment: Thank you, it works now, and I am definitely going to check out that website